# Can I use inheritance this way somehow

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Hi I would like use a virtual function of an inherited class without having to include it in the class prototype that would end up going in a header file. Is there any way to do this?

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void func () = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:

};

void Derived::func () {
return;
}
```

Is what I am thinking. In the case I am actually working with there are a large number of virtual function I may possibly use with any function and I don't want to bog down the class declaration with all the extra functions.

Comment: No, you cannot avoid it.  The reason?  How else would users of your header file (including the compiler) know that your class is non-abstract?

Comment: That's one of the biggest C++'s weakness. It causes much slower compilation speed. There's some solution to reduce this problem such as pimpl idiom, but it's still the problem.

Comment: @ikh: It's not clear what the relationship between this "problem" and compilation speed is?

Comment: "I don't want to bog down the class declaration..." - it sounds like you don't want to bog down the class declaration with declarations... ;o)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with plain inheritance / virtual functions, but you could inject your implementation of func:

```
// header file

#include <functional>

class Base {
public:
    Base(std::function<void()> func_impl)
        : m_func_impl{ std::move(func_impl) }
    {
    }

    void func() { m_func_impl(); }

private:
    std::function<void()> m_func_impl;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived();
};

// implementation file

static void Derived_func()
{
    // your implementation of func
}

Derived::Derived()
    : Base{ Derived_func }
{
}
```

You could accomplish the same by using the pimpl idiom. This avoids having a `std::function` for every method, but requires a secondary class hierachy:

```
// header file

#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    struct Impl
    {
        virtual ~Impl() {}
        virtual void func() = 0;
    };

    Base(std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl)
        : m_impl{ std::move(impl) }
    {
    }

    void func() { m_impl->func(); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived();
};

// implementation file

class Derived_Impl : public Base::Impl
{
    virtual void func() override
    {
        // your implementation of func
    }
};

Derived::Derived()
    : Base{ std::unique_ptr < Impl > {new Derived_Impl} }
{
}
```

Both solution have their drawbacks, most notably that the implementation is not within the derived class, so you have to think about how to adress scoping issues (e.g. accessing private members of the derived class in your implementations).